# Covert scree space to View Space/GUI Space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there any way available to convert screen space into view space as fig given.
[image]

Comment: Yes. What have you tried doing? And how is the world space in that figure relevant? (Also it does not really explain what you are exactly trying to convert)

Comment: question is simple how do i convert Screen Space(camera.pixel width and height into view space

Comment: By doing some pretty simple math (normalizing the coordinates into the desired range - a simple google search will give you all the relevant mathematical formulas for that). You still haven't shown what you have tried doing and where your problems are with that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to subtract the width of the x position of the mouse and subtract the height from the y position (I guess).

```
int x = MouseX - Width;
int y = MouseY - Height;
```

in win forms you can use Control.PointToClient but I dunno if it is usefull here